# External monitor can't be detected anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

Two days ago my MacBook Pro 13 stopped detecting external monitors.

I'm using a Unitek HDMI to USB-C dongle which I know works fine. I've tested 3 different monitors, that have different resolutions and refresh rates, they all work fine.

I've got another 2019 MacBook Pro 13" that works fine with every single monitor; using the same cable/dongle combo.

What I've tried:

- plugged the dongle with and without charger also being plugged in,
- plugged the dongle when Mac was sleeping/off
- plugged in a USB-C -> USB-A dongle and connected a mouse to it - both ports work fine,
- restarted my Mac after I've plugged the USB-C cable in,
- reset NVRAM and SMC,
- reinstalled OS (with and without backup)
- tried clicking "Detect Displays" in Displays settings,
- closed the lid, plugged the cable in, opened the lid,
- installed DisplayLink drivers, uninstalled them.

When I connect the dongle, it's visible as BillBoard Device in the System Information -> USB (both Macs have that). I've also been watching and comparing Console logs when I connect/disconnect the monitor and here are some things that I've noticed:

- The Mac that works fine has some [Hot_Plug] events visible when I plug in the monitor,
- FB0 both have DisplayPort driver version 1.1, FB1 on working Mac has a version 1.2 (this information doesn't show up on non-working Mac)

The screen doesn't flicker when I connect any external display, there's no Arrangements tab visible. AirPlay works fine.

Both Macs are 2019 13" Pro with the same stuff inside - they both use Intel Iris 645 Graphics.

Can I do anything so my Mac can detect these displays?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one thing to do.... take it in for service.

> When I connect the dongle it's visible as BillBoard Device in the
> System Information -> USB (both Macs have that).

The fact that it's being detected means your port is functioning.  Now, you didn't specifically say so, but I'm assuming that the built-in display is working.  Since you have the Intel Iris (Integrated) graphics, there's no failure with the graphics chipset (there's no discrete GPU)

However, there is a video mux (multiplexer) chip that "sends" video to the LCD, the external monitor, or both.  This has likely died.

- [Macbook Pro on but display is blank](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/374926/119271)

You've done a lot of diagnostics - actually gone a bit overboard with the re-installation of the OS.  Safe Mode or Recovery Mode is sufficient for this.  For the future, try this first and if you absolutely must have a clean install, do it to a USB flash drive (32GB is sufficient) so you're not wiping out your drive (and all your work) as a diagnostic procedure.

Comment: I was fine with wiping it clean as I only use it for work. I've tried Safe Boot and yes, my built-in display is working fine. I'll have to take it for service tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: What was the result of the service call @AbsoluteZero ?

Comment: @bmike They told me nothing is wrong and returned the Mac to me after a few days. It's been a few years ago, since then I got myself a new Mac. The old one started working after some time, randomly. It still works but only with certain displays.